# IONIC is giving me error on ios build

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to IONIC and iOS. I am working on a IONIC application everything is working fine on Windows laptop but when i try to build the application on iOs with such command `"ionic emulate iOS --target="iPhone-6s""` its giving me an error below

> Error: Expected "/* Begin ", "/* End ", "\"" or [A-Za-z0-9_.] but "<"
>   found.

It was working fine some time before on iOs too but don't know what happened all of sudden.

Comment: did you ever manage to find out what was causing this?